# About sql and logic. In the sql where clause, is "not (p and q)" equal to "(not p) or (not q)"

Tags: sql, logic

A SQL and logic problem. In the `where` clause, is

```
not (p and q)
```

equal to

```
(not p) or (not q)
```

Comment: Yes, the binary algebra apply to `WHERE` sql clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) are language-independent.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c040/5):

**Query 1: not (p and q)**

```
select * from table1
where
  !(p = 1 and q=1);
```

**Query 2 : (not p) or (not q)**

```
select * from table1
where p!=1 or q!=1;
```

There is no difference in the output and hence  the boolean algebra logic `!(p and Q) = (!p) or (!q)`  is true!!!

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit late answer but what you are talking about is `De Morgan's Law` here. So your logic `not (p and q)` will get converted to

```
not p or not q
```

Cause Negation (not) will apply to to the statement `(p and q)`

> not p
>
> `not and` will  get converted to `or`
>
> not q

Answer (score -1):

Although the two expressions are logically equivalent, they *may* not be functionally equivalent. It depends on the nature of `p` and `q` and the operation of the language's optimiser.

Consider, for instance, that `p` is false. In the case of `(not p) or (not q)`, we can deduce that the expression is true without having to evaluate `q`. A clever optimiser that understands `or` might take a short cut like that. But we cannot do so in the case of `not (p and q)` (unless our theorised optimiser could itself apply de Morgan first).

Does anyone know if SQL Server or Oracle or the other major players does this type of optimisation?

The result may not just be a performance saving. Suppose the `q` is not just a simple boolean variable but some expression that includes the execution of some more complex function. If that function has side-effects other than returning a truth value, then by optimising-out the evaluation of `q` we would also not see those side effects.